# Encrypt file using M2Crypto

Tags: python, encryption, m2crypto

It is known that I can read the whole file content in memory and encrypt it using the following code.

```
contents = fin.read()
cipher = M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher(alg="aes_128_cbc", key = aes_key, iv = aes_iv, op = 1)
encryptedContents = cipher.update(contents)
encryptedContents += cipher.final()
```

But what if the file size is large, is there a way for me to pass the input stream to M2Crypto instead of reading the whole file first?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a stream to it. But if I were to venture a guess, I'd you should be able user a fixed-size buffer, read the file into that, and keep running it through `.update()`, which spits out encrypted blocks. `.final()` looks like a method that creates padding for the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood that you can call .update(data) multiple times.

To minimise memory usage and use a file for output you should be able to do:

```
cipher = M2Crypto.EVP.Cipher(alg="aes_128_cbc", key = aes_key, iv = aes_iv, op = 1)
encrypted_contents_file = open(outfile_name, "w")

while True:
    buf = fin.read(1024)
    if not buf:
        break
    encrypted_contents_file.write(cipher.update(buf))

encrypted_contents_file.write( cipher.final() )
```